# What would you name this marketing tactics (scam) where an Business institution themselves post question and then self promote?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

What would you name this marketing tactics (scam) where an Business institution themselves (or any institute for that matter) posts a question like this one on a forum.

> Can anyone tell me about Brillianz Academy? how genuine is the institute?

And then their employees responds to it positively to attract random forum users to their institute.

I am looking for word or phrase such as clickbait that describes how online links are used to attract attention and to entice users to follow that link and browse. A existing or made-up word of phrase that bring the image of the scam.

In clickbait, the idea is to attract user to click and then bait them into possible business deal. In the above question the idea "posing as users-posting innocent question and self promotion baiting".

I have a feeling there would be a word/phrase for this idea in other fields already that might be apt.

Answer (score 7):

**sockpuppeting**

"Sockpuppeting" is when false identities are created online in order to deceptively not appear as oneself online but as another or others to propagandize by asking questions and giving opinions, to create an illusion that many hold the same opinion, to hype online buzz (i.e., generate a greater appearance of interest than actually exists), and to *spam*.

In business marketing, one may engage in sockpuppeting positively for one's own business and products and/or negatively against competitors' businesses and products.

As a practice, sockpuppeting is unethical. Social media platforms generally ban sockpuppeting by way of the terms and conditions they require users to agree to in order to set up an account on their platforms. Sockpuppeting isn't generally illegal, though, at least not in the United States since expressing opinions is *protected speech* under the First Amendment, the only illegality being if one is sockpuppeting speech that isn't *protected speech*, like libelous claims.

This link describes "sockpuppeting" in a general sense: http://changingminds.org/techniques/propaganda/sockpuppeting.htm

This link describes "sockpuppeting" in a business marketing context: https://www.ozbargain.com.au/wiki/help:sockpuppeting

Answer (score 1):

**gambit**, perhaps?

> A gambit is an action or set of actions, which you carry out in order to try to gain an advantage in a situation or game.

*He sees the proposal as more of a diplomatic gambit than a serious defense proposal.*

[Collins]

Another one: **marketing ploy**

> something that people who are selling a product use to make people want to buy the product

[Merriam-Webster]